# How can I find the primitive of $(x^3+x^2)/(4-x^2)$?

Tags: integration

I’m trying to find the primitive of the below rational function. I’m stuck trying to separate the undetermined coefficients like:

$$\frac{x^3+x^2}{(2-x)(2+x)}=\frac{A}{2-x}+\frac{B}{2+x}\iff x^3+x^2=A(2+x)+B(2-x)$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: you can approach this improperly by considering either $(x^3+x^2)\frac 1{4-x^2}$ or $(x^2+x)\frac x{4-x^2}$, but these approaches don’t yield the proper final form directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial fractions only work when the algebraic fraction is proper (that is, if $\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where $p,q$ are polynomials, then $\partial(p)<\partial(q)$.) You have to do long division to reduce the fraction to the form $$\frac{x^3+x^2}{4-x^2}=r(x)+\frac{p(x)}{4-x^2}$$ where $\partial(p)<2$ and $\partial(r)<3$.

Comment: Oh i had no ideia about that proper form,thanks for sharing.

Comment: You’re welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

$\dfrac{x^3+x^2}{(2-x)(2+x)}=-x-1+\dfrac{A}{2-x}+\dfrac{B}{2+x}$